# Is there any issue while replying to a comment using LinkedIn API

Tags: python-2.7, linkedin-api

We are using "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/" endpoint for replying/commenting. This endpoint was working fine but suddenly we noticed that some of the replies done for comments is not visible in LinkedIn websites.

When we tried to debug this problem we noticed that comments count is increasing but actual comment is not showing in LinkedIn website.

We have received replies done for comments using below API but replies are not showing on LinkedIn website.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/<parentID>/comments?oauth2_access_token=<token>&start=0&count=30
```

```
API = https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/<ugcpostID>/comments?oauth2_access_token=<token>
payload = {'message': {'text': u'Hi.'}, 'object': <ugcpostID>, 'parentComment': <parentID>, 'actor': <actorID>}
headers = {'x-li-format': 'json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
r = requests.post(API, data = json.dumps(payload),headers = headers)
```

Expected output is : Reply to comment done from API should show on LinkedIn

Comment: Wouldn't this be a great question for a linkedin support or bug report?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Kindly go through https://developer.linkedin.com/support/stackoverflow

Comment: Did _you_ read it? `Although LinkedIn's API support team monitors and contributes to the Stack Overflow community, it is ` **`not`** `appropriate to ask the kinds of questions that only a LinkedIn employee would be able to answer.` Changes in the API can only be ansered by the linkedin API support team... not by just any SO contributer... we are unable to tell you why stuff does not show on the linkedin sites. AFAICS you are asking about the API: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/ which is especially pointed out as not to ask here?